# How can I set up TeamCity agents to use separate maven local repositories?

Tags: maven-2, teamcity

I want to set up each TeamCity agent to use a local repository (maven.repo.local) in the agent's working directory (agent.work.dir).  Is it possible to configure maven properties to use TeamCity properties in this way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Enter `-Dmaven.repo.local=%system.agent.work.dir%/.m2` for the setting `Runner: Maven2` / `JVM command line parameters`

Comment: According to TeamCity 9+, `%system.agent.work.dir%` is depreciated in favour of `%teamcity.agent.work.dir%`

Comment: Been looking for this answer all day long!

Answer (score 2):

I don't use TeamCity, but Bamboo. The way I do this is for the maven goals, I have this defined:

```
-Dmaven.repo.local=${bamboo.M2REPOHOME}/${bamboo.buildKey} ...
```

Then the property M2REPOHOME is defined to be someplace on the filesystem, and bamboo.buildKey is the project name. I keep my m2 repositories all in one spot so I can easily nuke them. You should probably do something similar by setting `maven.repo.local` to the value of `agent.work.dir`, or someplace else. Quickly looking at the TeamCity docs, it looks like you would do something like this:

```
-Dmaven.repo.local=%agent.work.dir%/m2
```

Comment: The OP wanted an answer for TeamCity not Bamboo.